# How to automate svn and building process?

Tags: svn

After we tested the code in repository is OK,

how to automate the building process, say, updating the production code with those in svn?

If it matters, I'm talking about PHP source code.

Answer (score 1):

use one of continuous integration systems. they are many.
we use http://cruisecontrol.sourceforge.net and http://hudson-ci.org.
Also you could have a look at http://www.capify.org/index.php/Capistrano, here is the stackoverflow topic:
[SVN Website Development and Deployment Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1039741/svn-website-development-and-deployment-solution)