# Drupal: do you use SVN for websites development?

Tags: web, svn, drupal, version-control, drupal-6

Do you use Subversion while developing a website with drupal ?

I'm not talking about modules development, but websites development (i.e. adding hook functions, modifying template file.. etc)

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

Anything that's got any kind of ongoing development or is going to change over time should be version controlled.

Even if you're just doing a very small project, the value of having a version history is indesputable, and being able to make changes without worrying about overwriting someone else's updates is priceless.

Comment: So, let's say I'm working on my website online. You setup svn on the remote server to sync it with the main repository ?

Comment: @Patrick: There are many ways of managing deployment of your code. I found this SO question which has a number of possibly useful answers for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1039741/svn-website-development-and-deployment-solution

Comment: Patrick, that's right. Dreamhost makes that very easy for my personal website, because they have SVN management in their control panel.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, its's good keep a SVN repository synced with your local instance.For that purpose you can use Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but we are moving to git in the near future because it offers a better feature set (distributed SCM ftw) and more options for managing our code base (git submodules, stashing, better hook integration, better merging support, rebasing, and so much more). For the time being we've got our repos setup like so:

```
/trunk
/branches/6.x/1.x/core
/branches/6.x/1.x/sitename.domain.edu
/branches/6.x/1.x/sitename2.domain.edu
/branches/6.x/1.1.x/core
/branches/6.x/1.1.x/sitename.domain.edu
...
/tags/6.x/1.x/core
/tags/6.x/1.x/sitename.domain.edu
/tags/6.x/1.x/sitename2.domain.edu
/tags/6.x/1.1.x/core
/tags/6.x/1.1.x/sitename.domain.edu
...
```

Each branch is a `svn copy` of the trunk repo (where we do most of our development) and each tag is a `svn copy` of it's corresponding branch. The `core` branch is the primary distro that we distribute to all of our sites that share the university's look and feel, and each subsite is a site with special modules, custom theme, or any other functionality that isn't part of the primary distro.  It makes moving between drupal releases a lot easier, but you can start to run into problems merging occasionally. Also you run into performance issues when the repo starts to grow, which is part of the reasoning behind moving to git.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Version control is critical. Distributed version control systems such as Git, Mercurial, and Bazaar are particularly nice, and let you start committing immediately, without the need to push those changes to a central server.

My Drupal workflow: use Mercurial and its sub-repositories feature to create independent repositories for 1) Drupal + contributed modules, 2) theme, and 3) custom modules. That way, I can clone from a single URL, get my entire project, and be able to track changes to each distinct piece independently.